# Calculus chain rule taking derivative twice

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I figure out the following question.

Find $f''(x)$ if $f(x)=(x^2-6x-7)^{11}$

Using the chain rule I got the first derivative as.

$11(x^2-6x-7)^{10}(2x-6)$

Applying both the chain rule and the product rule I got

for my second derivative

$f''(x)=11(x^2-6x-7)^{10}(2)+(2x-6)(110)(x^2-6x-7)^9(2x-6)$

However did I do this correctly?

Comment: It looks good to me. Typo, $f(x)''$ in last row.

Comment: The "prime" should come after the $f$. It is the function that you are differentiating. Hence $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ are correct while $f(x)'$ and $f(x)''$ are incorrect.

Comment: yes that is true.

Comment: [Yes!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double+derivative+of+%28x%5E2-6x-7%29%5E%2811%29)

Comment: Hmm in wolfram alpha it is written differently but I guess it is simplified If I try and simplify it I will probably make an error...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct.

Alternatively you could write $x^2-6x-7=(x+1)(x-7)$ so you can differentiate twice: $$(x+1)^{11}(x-7)^{11}$$

using just the product rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can further simplify it as

$(-x^2 + 6x + 7)^9(-22x^2 + 132x - 440(x - 3)^2 + 154)$

or rearranging signs

$(x^2 - 6x - 7)^9(22x^2 - 132x + 440(x - 3)^2 - 154)$

and finally

$22(x^2 - 6x - 7)^9(21x^2 - 126x + 173)$

Comment: Your simplify routine seems to add a few too many minus signs.